# Laravel Auth::login($user) not working properly

Tags: authentication, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I am trying to login user but I get the following error everytime:

> ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 439:
>   Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, array given

Here is my form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ route('login') }}">
{{ csrf_field() }}
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"><br>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password"><br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

and here is my route:

```
Route::post('login/', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'UsersController@login']);
```

and login method in `UsersController`:

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required']);
    $user = $request->all();
    Auth::login($user);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Its `Auth::attempt`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are wanting to log a user in then you want to use `Auth::attempt()` rather than `Auth::login()`.

> [`Auth::attempt()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#authenticating-users) accepts an array of key / value pairs as its first argument. The values in the array will be used to find the user in your database table.

So in your code this would be:

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email', 'password' => 'required']);
    $user = $request->all();
    Auth::attempt($user);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

You would use [`Auth::login()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#included-authenticating) to manually log an existing user in to your application. The object provided needs to be an implementation of the `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` which is already implemented inside the default `App\User` model. For example, this could look like this:

```
public function manualLogin(){
    $user = User::find(1);
    Auth::login($user);
    return redirect('/');
}
```

You can read more about this on the docs, which I have linked above.